# What does setting the SelectedIndex to -1 on a drop down list do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a simple question here. I have seen drop down list indexes get set to -1 when it is being reset.

What is this line of code doing?

```
myDropDownList.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

How can it be set with a value less than 0?

Thank you!

Comment: It means no selection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-1 indicates that there is no SelectedIndex .  Setting SelectedIndex to -1 will show the first item in the list when you load the page.

Comment: Awesome. Well that is simple enough. Thank you.

Comment: pretty much sums it up

Comment: Pretty sure it doesn't show blank unless that is specifically the first item in the DropDownList. It should show index 0, IIRC.

Comment: Well I would be interested to know what it does. Does it show the first item or no value.

Comment: You could always give it a test run. I just did. Shows index 0 for me.

Comment: Just tested. It does in fact show 0.  In fact, it even changes selectedIndex to 0.  This is different functionality than a combobox on a windows form which shows blank.  If you're looking for the first entry to be empty, you will have to add an empty entry